# How do i signing both v1 and v2 scheme in a minisdkversion >= 24 apk

Tags: android, android-app-signing

Here is the signing configs:

> ````
>     ...
>     minSdkVersion 24 }
>
> release {
>     ...
>     v1SigningEnabled true
>     v2SigningEnabled true } ```
> ````

Here is the apksigner verify result:

> ```
> Verifies  
> Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false  
> Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true  
> Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false  
> Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false  
> Verified for SourceStamp: false  
> Number of signers: 1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect because your minSdkVersion is 24, apksigner is smart enough to realize you don't need v1 Signing scheme to work on all Android versions you target.

Since V2 signing supersedes v1 signing, signing with v1 would only make your app bigger for no benefit.

Comment: Due to some Android market are only support v1 scheme for uploading apk, so i need to include both v1 and v2 signing in one apk.

Comment: Got it. I would suggest to file a bug with Gradle to understand why the v1SigningEnabled is not respected and especially explain your use-case. But I suspect this might be an issue with the store because if Android verifies one signature but the store you're using verifies another signature, then the security model of the store is effectively broken (you can imagine an APK v1-signed with one key and v2-signed with another key).